# Kubernetes- 403 forbidden issue

Tags: docker, docker-compose, azure-devops, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks

I am deploying java service from VSTS to Docker and then to Kubernetes. I am able to push  and run image successfully from ACR. After pushing into Kubernetes, I am not able to browse the service from Kubernetes.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind : Deployment
metadata : 
  name: xservice
  labels: 
    app: xserviceapi
spec: 
  template: 
    metadata: 
      labels: 
        app: xserviceapi
        type : Back-end
    spec: 
      containers: 
      - name: xservice
        image : acr.azurecr.io/xservice:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports: 
        - containerPort: 80
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: regcre
  replicas: 1
  selector: 
   matchLabels: 
    app: xserviceapi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: xservice
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 80
  selector:
    app: xserviceapi
```

Comment: give us this command output ?
`kubectl get services`

Comment: NAME         TYPE           CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)        AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP      10.0.0.1      <none>          443/TCP        3d
taxservice   LoadBalancer   10.0.84.247   40.68.134.174   80:31679/TCP   3d                                                                                                           
                                                                                                               @Onur yartasi

Comment: Your service is loadbalancer, you can able to 40.68.134.174 ip address

Comment: @Onur Yartasi - We tried with same IP, but still no luck. Do we need to expose anything in Inbound port of the agent node?

Answer (score 0):

As @OnurYartaşi mentioned, you should be able to reach your service using 40.68.134.174 IP address.

Comment: It didnt work!! do we need to specify the nodeport in YAML and create corresponding inbound port in Agent node?

Comment: @Girish but it should work if your service is OK and running on a port 80. Maybe you can share a `kubectl get pods` result? Also, if you get code '403' on that IP, is it from your app or from LoadBalancer? What is in an application logs?